# Give one array to mutltiple methods

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example, we have 5 courses available: comp2011, comp2012, comp2013, comp2014, comp2015.

When adding or dropping a course, you need to specify the student's name (you may assume it is unique) and the course that is going to be added/dropped.

For adding a course, if the student has already enrolled in at least one course, the system will append the newly added course to his/her course record. But if it is the first time the student is trying to add courses, the system will create a record for him/her and state that this is the first course of this student (see sample output below)...

The system should support listing the courses that the student has enrolled in.

The system should support some basic validation check: Students cannot add the same course two times nor drop a course that is not enrolled.

When dropping the last course, there will be nothing in the student course list, but the system should still keep the empty file for him/her so that when another course is added, it knows that this is not the first time.

How Can I Make the Array that is going to support all my methods at once knowing that I made a method for adding, dropping, listing and quitting.(Quiting is not having an array)

This is where I am at now:

```java
import java.util.*;
public class codeTraining {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String AddDrop = "";
        while (!AddDrop.equals("Q")) {
            System.out.println("Add-Drop Course Menu");
            System.out.println("A for Add, D for Drop, L for List, Q for Quit");
            AddDrop = input.nextLine();
            switch (AddDrop) {
                case "A" -> A();
                case "D" -> D();
                case "L" -> L();
                case "Q" -> Q();
                default -> System.out.println("Please enter a valid Character!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void A() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String course;
        System.out.println("Please enter the student name:");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the course you want to add:");
        course = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Adding course : " + course);
        System.out.println("Add course successfully");
    }

    public static void D() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a student name");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("please enter the course you want to drop:");
        String course = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Dropping course: " + course);
        System.out.println("Drop course successfully");
    }

    public static void L() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name, course;
        System.out.println("Please enter the student name");
        name = input.nextLine();
    }

    public static void Q() {
        System.out.println("Quit...");
    }
}
```

Comment: I see at least two arrays needed; one for Student's and one for Course's. It would be better with ArrayList's, though. Does your teacher allow you to use them?

Comment: @NomadMaker Yes, We can use ArrayList.I think we should make a double dimensional Array of student containing courses. But the thing is how to make all the methods Be linked to the same multidimensional-array?

Comment: Try not to make two-dimensional lists for this. Think of objects. A Course could contain a list of students.

Comment: @NomadMaker I see. Could I have a bit more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a hashmap for this problem, as it will allow you to quickly and easily look up the courses of students. It's declared as a global variable outside all of the methods, which means it can be accessed by any of them.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class codeTraining {
    //Hashmap contains names that are mapped to lists of courses
    static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map =
            new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String AddDrop = "";
        while (!AddDrop.equals("Q")) {
            System.out.println("Add-Drop Course Menu");
            System.out.println("A for Add, D for Drop, L for List, Q for Quit");
            AddDrop = input.nextLine();
            //added breaks to the switch statement
            switch (AddDrop) {
                case "A": A(); break;
                case "D": D(); break;
                case "L": L(); break;
                case "Q": Q(); break;
                default: System.out.println("Please enter a valid Character!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void A() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String course;
        System.out.println("Please enter the student name:");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the course you want to add:");
        course = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Adding course : " + course);
        //if the map contains the name already
        if (map.containsKey(name)) {
            //if the student already had the course in its list
            if (map.get(name).contains(course)) {
                System.out.println("The student is already taking this course");
                return;
            } else {
                //adding the course to the list that's mapped
                //to the student's name in the hashmap 
                map.get(name).add(course);
            }
        }
        //if student isn't in the system
        else {
            //create a new arraylist with the new course in it
            ArrayList<String> courses = new ArrayList<String>();
            courses.add(course);
            //add a map between the student's name and his course list
            map.put(name, courses);
        }
        System.out.println("Add course successfully");
    }

    public static void D() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a student name");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("please enter the course you want to drop:");
        String course = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Dropping course: " + course);
        //checks if name in system
        if (map.containsKey(name)) {
            if (map.get(name).contains(course)) {
                //removing if list had the course in it
                map.get(name).remove(course);
            } else {
                System.out.println("This student isn't taking that course");
                return;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("This student isn't in the system");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Drop course successfully");
    }

    public static void L() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name, course;
        System.out.println("Please enter the student name");
        name = input.nextLine();
        if (map.containsKey(name)) {
            //printing out courses for specified student
            ArrayList<String> courses = map.get(name);
            for (int i = 0; i < courses.size(); i++) {
                System.out.print(courses.get(i) + " ");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("This student isn't in the system");
        }
    }

    public static void Q() {
        System.out.println("Quit...");
    }
}
```

I added some comments in case you were new to hashmaps. Basically, `map.put(key, value)` will add a mapped pair to the list so that when you call `map.get(key)`, it will return whatever value you put it to. I hope this helps, and feel free to ask if you're confused.

Comment: Thank you for the clear, well-structured, and very clear code sir! @Sankeeth Ganeswaran

Comment: No problem, feel free to click the checkmark to accept answer if it helped :)